# Thick line with a number on top

Tags: notation, rests

What is the meaning of the thick line with an 8 on top in the image below?

I have looked everywhere on the web, but can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: A thick horizontal serifed line in the centre of a measure with a bold "8" above it]

Answer (score 11):

It denotes multi-bar rests.  The number above the bar is the number of bars that are filled with whole rests.  It's done this way to be easier to read (you don't have to be looking at the page for each specific bar) and to save paper.

Comment: Yes, this is a multi-measure rest. It is equal to 8 bars of rest.

Answer (score 1):

For shorter multi-measure rests (lilypond has the default boundary 10) there exists another notation, where you have the same number above, but longa and brevis rest symbols (vertical) in the stave. For an example see, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_(music)), section *Multiple measure rests*.