# What does this horizontal bar at the first measure mean?

Tags: notation, rests

I was looking at some sheet music when I came across something I am seeing for the first time. It looked like a horizontal bar on the first measure. Here is an image:

[image: Bar with "15" above the staff]

What does this bar tell you? What is it for?

Comment: Duplicate: [Thick line with a number on top](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/72191/thick-line-with-a-number-on-top)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is a multi-measure rest. The numeral 15 above it indicates that it is equivalent to writing out fifteen bars of full-measure rests. This is done to save space, for example in orchestral parts.

Comment: It also saves you from having to count all 15 measures and praying you didn't miscount.

Comment: You still have to count to 15, but at least you know it's 15 that you have to count to...

Comment: Note, that for less than 15 full measuress a different notation exists using whole rest and vertical lines representing 2 or 4 measures of rest, see [lilypond documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rests.html).

Comment: @guidot that is true, and it's well worth knowing both kinds of notation.  As a personal preference, I'd rather see this symbol for 4 measures or more.

Comment: @guidot I've never seen those rests used for multimeasure rests - they're just for notes longer than semibreves. Just like it's not conventional to notate an eight-beat note in 4/4 by writing a single breve, you also wouldn't notate two bars of rest by using a breve rest. Every piece of music I've played that was written in modern notation either wrote out each bar of rest or put a number over it to indicate multiple bars.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ...provided the numerals are clearly written. I've had to distinguish between 1 and 7, 5 and 3 (!) based on the longa/breve notation before!

Comment: @MatthewWalton: You are mistaken here.If you don't trust lilypond , Elaine Goulds *Behind Bars* has a nice explanation in the section *multiple rests*. It seems mostly be used in orchestral parts, but I have surely seen it much more often than breve rests.

Comment: @guidot I don't see where Lilypond defines them as multimeasure rests. It explains various rest durations using `r` and `\maxima`, and multimeasure rests using `R`, but never says they're the same thing. I don't doubt that you've seen the usage you say you have, but it strikes me as very unusual to stick a longa rest in the middle of something in 4/4 and expect people to correctly read it as meaning they have to rest for four bars. That's more like I'd expect to see when playing from facsimile of early printed music.

Comment: @MatthewWalton: I consider the section [Full measure rests](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rests.html#full-measure-rests) as pretty convincing as well as my first look at a Schubert Symphony at [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ReverseLookup/36187), Bassoon/2nd movement, page 3 sports **seven** occurrences in the first two lines...

Comment: " a different notation exists"   True.  But it's antique.

Comment: @Laurence the notation may be antique, but if an orchestra has a full set of antique parts they are more likely to spend any money they have buying new music than updating old music. As always - *use* the new standard but be able to understand the old one.